# Download files from server Asp .net Core

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

**my web host server xxxx.sth is windows**

**my file server zzz.xxx.sth is linux**

**My files are located in zzz.xxx.sth and my host is on xxx.sth**
and I want to make some protocols or whatever to download from server.

**Imagine I have web application that people search about pdf file and after finding file, I should give them a link for download.**

This is my issue that how to create ling between host and download server By the way I am using Asp.net core .

*There is no application running on file server*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using SFTP by connecting from the host to a remote Linux server using the ssh.net library
Stages:
1)Connect to the Linux server via sftp
2) Find the required file in the directories
3) Read the file
4) Give the file to the user via "Return File"

However, you need to understand what you are using to connect a Linux user

There is another option. You create a small API on the Links server that looks through files using a key and sends There is another option. You create a small API on the Links server that looks through files using a key and send

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to find a library of NFS client for .NET. You could mount the NFS server by windows first. And then access the windows path instead.

To enable this, visit control panel --> turn on/off windows feature --> service for nfs

[image]

After unable the nfs function, you could execute the following command in command prompt:

```
showmount -e zzz.xxx.sth   //check your nfs folder.
mount -o anon \\zzz.xxx.sth\nfs_share_folder Z:  // mount the nfs folder to windows path `Z:\`
```

Then in the project you could make a file download api like following:

```
    [HttpGet("DownloadFile")]
    public IActionResult DownloadFile()
    {
        var path = Path.Combine("Z:\\Sample.pdf"); 
        byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path); //get bytes

        var contentType = "";
        new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider().TryGetContentType(path, out contentType);

        var result = new GetFileDownload()
        {
            Result = "OK",
            FileName = "Sample.pdf",
            MimeType = contentType,
            File = bytes
        };

        return result == null ? NotFound() : Ok(result);
    }
```